# Why would uncle Vernon speak tongue-tying curse?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> But Hagrid simply waved his hand and said, “About our world, I mean.
>   Your world. My world. Yer parents’ world.” “What world?” Hagrid looked
>   as if he was about to explode. “DURSLEY!” he boomed. Uncle Vernon, who
>   had gone very pale, whispered something that sounded like
>   “**Mimblewimble**.” “But yeh must know about yer mom and dad,” he
>   said. “I mean, they're famous. You're famous.”

It's from Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, chapter 4, The Keeper of the Keys.

Does he curse Hagrid to lose sound? Does the word "Mimblewimble" sound like anything meaningful with it, so that he would choose to say it? It can't be a coincidence. I'd like to know what's the idea that comes to mind when hearing 'Mimblewimble'.

Comment: The word *mimblewimble* is nonsense in English, but might be interested in the word ***mumble***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**He doesn't; this came long before "Mimblewimble" was meant to be the Tongue-Tying Curse.**

"Mimblewimble" only because known as the incantation for the Tongue-Tying Curse when [*Harry Potter: Hogwarts Mystery*](https://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter:_Hogwarts_Mystery) came out in April 2018, 20 years after *The Philosopher's Stone* came out.

This is likely simply a reference to when Vernon said this; at the time that the novel was written, "Mimblewimble" was not intended to be the Tongue-Tying Curse.

Instead, this is supposed to tell you that Vernon was very scared of Hagrid, because there's a humongous person shouting at him (it uses the word "boomed", indicating that Hagrid was speaking very loudly), scaring Vernon enough that he couldn't even talk properly. He only managed to mumble something while going *very pale*, something that usually happens when you're scared.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it's not the Tongue-Tying Curse he try to speak out, it had nothing to do with it. But it also doesn't sound like just a frightened mutter, does it? is it possible that he is cursing Hagrid, but known it won't work. Don't you think the word sounds like a curse? In my language, some nonsense word just sounds like curses.

Comment: @狗撸撸 - Vernon wouldn't know any Wizarding curses; he despises the magic world and knows nothing about it, so there's no possible way he would know that curse.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a wizarding curse, don't normal people make curse-sound to abuse at someone else? It's not usual but you can image in some senses. I see, I overthought it.

Comment: @狗撸撸 - You've asked a fair question. In this case, I think "mimblewimble* is just meant to be a silly [nonsense word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonsense_word), made to show that Vernon could not make any intelligible sounds. It's possible that Rowland picked _mimblewimble_ because it's similar to the word [_mumbo-jumbo_](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/mumbo-jumbo).